# Convert Jq to js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i can't add Jquery library to my codes and i have to use js code

can somebody help me with converting following code to js

thanks ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#gorightslide").click(function(){
            if(!$(this).is('.diactiveisbtn')){
                $(this).addClass('diactiveisbtn');
                $("#goleftslide").removeClass('diactiveisbtn');
                $("#oneblockshowblog").css({display:'none'});
                $("#twoblockshowblog").fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
        $("#goleftslide").click(function(){
            if(!$(this).is('.diactiveisbtn')){
                $(this).addClass('diactiveisbtn');
                $("#gorightslide").removeClass('diactiveisbtn');
                $("#twoblockshowblog").css({display:'none'});
                $("#oneblockshowblog").fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please note stackoverflow is not code conversion service and Java != Javascript.

Comment: the main thing you need to know (that will help with much of it) is `$('#id')` can be replaced with `document.getElementById('id')` - then you need to learn how to use things like `.addEventListener` `.classList` `.style` - and make some css animations for the fadeIn stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementById("gorightslide").click(function(){
        if(!hasClass(this, 'diactiveisbtn')){
            this.className += " diactiveisbtn";
            document.getElementById("goleftslide").className = document.getElementById("goleftslide").className.replace(/\diactiveisbtn\b/,'');
            document.getElementById("oneblockshowblog").style.display = "none";
            fadeIn(document.getElementById("twoblockshowblog"));
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("goleftslide").click(function(){
        if(!hasClass(this, 'diactiveisbtn')){
            this.className += " diactiveisbtn";
            document.getElementById("gorightslide").className = document.getElementById("gorightslide").className.replace(/\diactiveisbtn\b/,'');
            document.getElementById("twoblockshowblog").style.display = "none";
            fadeIn(document.getElementById("oneblockshowblog"));
        }
    });
});

function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

function fadeIn(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;

  var last = +new Date();
  var tick = function() {
    el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / 400;
    last = +new Date();

    if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };

  tick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    function yourfunction() {
  document.getElementById("gorightslide").onclick = function(event) {
    if(event.target.className != "diactiveisbtn"){
        event.target.classList = "diactiveisbtn";
        document.getElementById("goleftslide").classList = "";
        document.getElementById("oneblockshowblog").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("twoblockshowblog").style.display = "block"; // you can add here css animation (@keyframe)
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("goleftslide").onclick = function(event) {
    if(event.target.className != "diactiveisbtn"){
        event.target.classList = "diactiveisbtn";
        document.getElementById("gorightslide").classList = "";
        document.getElementById("twoblockshowblog").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("oneblockshowblog").style.display = "block"; // you can add here css animation (@keyframe)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a misunderstanding here, Jquery is made it with javascript, so, Your code is already in javascript. If you want to use this code in one function, you only need to remove the first line, it will looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callingPlugin(){
        $("#gorightslide").click(function(){
            if(!$(this).is('.diactiveisbtn')){
                $(this).addClass('diactiveisbtn');
                $("#goleftslide").removeClass('diactiveisbtn');
                $("#oneblockshowblog").css({display:'none'});
                $("#twoblockshowblog").fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
        $("#goleftslide").click(function(){
            if(!$(this).is('.diactiveisbtn')){
                $(this).addClass('diactiveisbtn');
                $("#gorightslide").removeClass('diactiveisbtn');
                $("#twoblockshowblog").css({display:'none'});
                $("#oneblockshowblog").fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
    };
    callingPlugin(); // <-- Will execute the code
</script>
```

Comment: so ... all those lines with `$(` are not jquery? - almost every single line of that code requires the jquery library

Comment: thought he was having a misunderstanding on what is Jquery and what is Javascript.. you right!